# Phonegap/Jquery Mobile Android app - Form submission affecting navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have built a jquerymobile Android app and all is working well other than a form submission issue which is driving me nuts.

Basically - if you enter text and click the physical search button - the search function works great - but if you enter text and click the enter button the app navigates to the homepage....  How can I stop this happening?

This is my form

```
<form  class="srchForm" action="searchThis()">
    <input type="search" class="srchInput">
    <div class="clearBtn"><span class="hidden">Clear</span></div>
    <div class="srchBtnOne"><span class="hidden">Search</span></div>
</form>


function searchThis() {

     event.preventDefault();

     var inputDetails= $('.srchInput').val();

     $('.srchRes').empty();
     $('.srchRes').append('<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300"    frameborder="0"   src="http://uc.dialogue.netsrch.jsp?query='+inputDetails+'&searchMode=any&indexGroup="  style=" border:none;background:#FFF; overflow:none; width:300px;"></iframe>');
}
```

I thought i'd solved this with the event.preventdefault();  but its still causing issues..
Can anyone suggest anything?

cheers
paul

Answer (score 1):

this was the only way I could solve the issue -

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  searchThis()
     return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Mobile framework is probably still hi-jacking the form submission for it's own AJAX handling of form submission. To stop this either disable the AJAX handling of forms globally or disable AJAX on your form individually like this:

```
<form  class="srchForm" action="searchThis()" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="search" class="srchInput">
    <div class="clearBtn"><span class="hidden">Clear</span></div>
    <div class="srchBtnOne"><span class="hidden">Search</span></div>
</form>
```

- Global Configuration for jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html
- Submitting Forms in jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Comment: Thanks Jasper, the data-ajax="false" just caused the app to crash for me for some reason - I solved it with the keydown fix above eventually.  Thanks for trying though..

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

 $( document ).delegate("#index", "pageshow",function(event){
        $('#index #searchForm').bind('submit',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;
        });
        $("#index #searchformbtn").unbind("blur");
        $("#index #searchformbtn").bind('blur',function(event){
             var inputDetails= $('.srchInput').val();
         $('.srchRes').empty();
         $('.srchRes').append('<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300"    frameborder="0"   src="http://uc.dialogue.netsrch.jsp?query='+inputDetails+'&searchMode=any&indexGroup="  style=" border:none;background:#FFF; overflow:none; width:300px;"></iframe>');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Cheers for you help, no luck though unfortunately - the form is actually on a page called srch, i altered your code above to suit but it still sends the app to the  homepage..